# How does Google keep track of map loads without API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing Google Maps in my web application. Since Version 3 I don't need an API key for accessing their servers.

[Google is limiting the requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage_limits), though.

How are they doing that? If external users are accessing my website, one map load is generated.

> Do I have now about 25,000 map loads per IP address or how to they
>   recognize my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use the location/domain of the current document(this detail will be sended to the Authentication-service).

But as long as it's not documented this may only be an assumption, you'll have to ask google how they do it.